# Qt - парсинг запроса на сервере в QTcpSocket

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, tcp

Есть сервер TCP `QTcpServer tcp` и сокет подключения `QTcpSocket socket`.

Подключаю я их вот так:

```
connect(tcp, &QTcpServer::newConnection, this, &Server::slotNewConnection); // в Server::Server()
connect(socket, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, this, &Server::slotServerRead); // в Server::slotNewConnection()
```

Мне на сокет приходит вот такой текст:

> GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:1234\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101
> Firefox/71.0\r\nAccept:
> text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Language:
> en-US,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nConnection:
> keep-alive\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\nContent-Length:
> 10\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\n\r\ntype=check

Есть ли нормальный способ спарсить все это или надо вручную это делать? В ноде, например, есть цивилизованный [способ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306569/what-does-body-parser-do-with-express).

Кстати, там еще в запросе есть параметр "type = check", которого в этой строке нет.

Comment: Для http в qt есть более подходящие классы https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkrequest.html

Comment: я не уверен, есть ли оно пока в релиз-версии кьюта, но вам надо вот это https://www.qt.io/blog/2019/01/25/introducing-qt-http-server . На данный момент вы работаете насырую с хттп данными

Comment: @goldstar_labs Как это собрать и подключить?

Comment: честно - хз, у кьюта были планы релизнуть хттп-сервер, это минимум который я смог нагуглить